# List of Images from Submitted Directory Name via HTML Form

Tags: php, jquery, directory

I've searched SO for answers to this feature I desire, but what I need is somewhat unique?

I've got an input element, I type in the name of a sub-folder, hit submit, and a list of the image names within that specified folder is generated via PHP or other. This is local, nothing fancy.

```
<form action="Make_List.php" method="post">
<input type=text name="location"/>
<input type=submit/>
</form>

<div id="List_Generated"> //desired output.
<span>A.jpg</span>
<span>B.jpg</span>
<span>C.jpg</span>
<span>D.png</span>
</div>
```

I have no idea what to put in Make_List.php, or if it'll even work locally. I did find this online:

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "../images/team/harry/" ( + sub-folder name );

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
echo $image;
}
```

But Firefox doesn't know what to do, it asks me to open or save the .php file. Some similar questions on SO (the local part) imply that I don't need PHP for this?

Any tips or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: You have to run PHP in some form of server environment. I'm afraid you can't just run it from you filesystem. Search for 'MAMP' if you are on a Mac, or 'WAMP' if you are on Windows to set up a local web server for your development.

Comment: @uotonyh - is there some alternative I could use that works locally without bothering with server stuff?

Comment: @Jason No, you need `server stuff` for getting `server` information.

Comment: @uotonyh - Just to be sure, the directory I want to list is just a folder on my computer. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP needs a server environment to be processed.  You can run a server locally on your own computer.  Google installing apache + php.  If you have hosting that supports the PHP language you can test your code there.

Your web browser does not run PHP code. An interpreter runs the scripts and their are modules to plug the PHP interpreter into an http server  ie apache.  Apache will then run the code and return the results if it is instructed to process the .php with a certain module through its configuration.

Comment: What if I just want to list the contents of a folder on my computer? Possible or no?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
//path to directory to scan 
$directory = "full/path/to/images/team/harry/" . $_POST['location'];

foreach (glob($directory."*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better example for you to work with, no need to type a subdir:

```
<?php 
//Get subfolder list
$folders = glob('../images/team/harry/*',GLOB_ONLYDIR);
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name="location" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
<option>-Choose Subdir-</option>
<?php
foreach($folders as $folder){
    echo '<option value="'.basename($folder).'">'.basename($folder).'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</select>
</form>

<?php
//List of files once post was submitted
if(isset($_POST['location'])){
    echo '<div id="List_Generated">';
    $files = glob('../images/team/harry/'.basename($_POST['location']).'/*.jpg');
    foreach($files as $file){
        echo '<span>'.basename($file).'</span>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: The OP is trying to use this code to access files on the *client*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of thing can be done but with limitations as follows:

- Must use HTML5 (doctype and markup).
- Google Chrome only (for now)
- Application-specific "sandbox" area only, not your general file system.

Realistically, you are thus limited to your computer(s) or those in an intranet where each computer's environment is controlled; not the internet at large.

I'm not an expert but [here's a good introduction](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). You need to read at least the Intro and the section entitled "Reading a directory's contents".